# SMTP queueing not working?

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

i'm trying to send bulk newsletters using SMTP server. My problem is when i'm sending newsletters, if another user log in and send newsletters from his system, the mails i were sending get failed and his mails are sent successfully. Can anyone please help me find the problem, how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide example code.

Comment: Could you provide relevant entries from sendmail (SMTP/MTA server) log files?